# What was the approximate cost of 1 ETH during pre-launch (Aug 2014)

Tags: ether, history, presale

The ETH pre-launch allowed people to exchange Bitcoins for ETH at a determined value.

What was this exchange rate in USD?

```
E.g. 1 Bitcoin got you X Eth, which was worth about $Y.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Ethereum presale took place from *Tuesday, 22 July 2014* to *Tuesday, 2 September 2014* (42 days).

```
22 July to 5 August 2014:     2000 ETH      = 1 BTC = 572-632 USD 
6 August to 2 September 2014: 1999-1337 ETH = 1 BTC = 592-471 USD
```

USD prices are the range in the given period of 24 averages on multiple exchanges, Source: [Quandl](https://www.quandl.com/data/BAVERAGE/USD-USD-BITCOIN-Weighted-Price)

For the linear decrease of ETH in the second period, refer to this source:

> The price of ether is initially set to a discounted price of 2000 ETH
>   per BTC, and will stay this way for 14 days before linearly declining
>   to a final rate of 1337 ETH per BTC. The sale will last 42 days,
>   concluding at 23:59 Zug time September 2.

https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/07/22/launching-the-ether-sale/

More information about how it turned out:
https://blog.ethereum.org/2014/08/08/ether-sale-a-statistical-overview/

Answer (score 8):

1 Bitcoin got you 2000 ETH and at the time 1 Bitcoin was somewhere around $500 - $600, but you can check that bit.